# Confused about Min SDK Version

Tags: android

I am referring to the http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html regarding activity testing.

My avd is showing platform-2.3.3 api level-10.

In eclipse when i click on create new android project and select create project from existing source and then browse to the samples\android-8\Spinner it prefill the Min Sdk Version with 3 and when i select the target platform 2.3.3 api level 10 it shows following warning:

```
The API level for the selected SDK target does not match the Min SDK Version.
```

I have checked the spinner manifest file it contains

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

I have tried different combinations like changed the sample folder and changed the target but it shows the same warning.

I want to know how to rectify the warning so that my sample run?

Please help me on this

Comment: If it's just a warning then you should be able to ignore it safely.

Answer (score 2):

min sdk version can be lower than target sdk version.
[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

Comment: Hi bob thanks for replying i have read this but i want to know how to make the sample run?

Answer (score 2):

The app uses level 10 sdk I guess and the minsdklevel specified is 3 that is the reason for the warning. This warning can be ignored.

You can run the app on any version of android with level >= 3 as long you dont use any api calls which where introduced in level 10.

Comment: Thanks josnidhin for replying. Target & avd api level 10 but the sample application manifest file contains sdk version 3. Is there a way to modify this?

Comment: You can do what Torp suggested. But I think the warning can be ignored.