# How does build target effects an android application?

Tags: android, android-manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

While developing android apps in Eclipse we have to specify the build target for our app.
I want to know that how does it effect the application ?
I mean I have chosen my build target as - 
**"Google APIs " Platform-version -3.0 API level -11**

As far as I know the min-SDK version in the manifest file decides that which devices the application will run on. I just want to make sure that I am right and choosing build target will not effect this part of my app (devices capable of running it).

Please tell me about this.