# How do I emulate a HoneyComb-compatible app on older emulators?

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I began the process of making one of my apps Honeycomb-friendly.

I started by changing the project's target build to version 11, and edited to AndroidManifest.xml to use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

These are the *only* changes I made so far. I am able to test it perfectly on my Honeycomb tablet device.

However, I cannot get Eclipse to launch this app in an older emulator (e.g. version 9). Technically speaking, the app should run in older android versions, so what can I do to test this app for older devices?

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: are you using an API calls from version 11?

Comment: @slayton I plan on using at a minimum the holographic theme. So I will need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be some sort of bug. When my 3.1 device is plugged into my PC, Eclipse/Android won't let me launch a new emulator that's < 3.0.

I worked around this by launching the emulator before I plug in my device, and then it has no problems deploying the app to both of the running devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on this front but setting the minSdkVersion  different from the targetSdkVersion doesn't make the app automatically use a different API level based on the device. See this:
[Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

and this:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

I suspect that because your application is using level 11 apis it won't run on a device that is of a previous API level.

Comment: I understand. Once again, I had not used any newer APIs yet. I am planning on doing so in the future.