# Device Compatibility Issue with Samsung Galaxy Mini

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in the android market that is reporting incomparability and so cannot be installed on a Samsung Galaxy Mini. Developer Console says that it is due to my manifest settings.

My manifest is very light : android 1.5 or above and bare bones permissions so I'm surprised that this is the problem.

My question is in 2 parts:

1. Are there any tools to help diagnose device and app compatibility.
2. What is the problem with my manifest?

Here is my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.basl.bugsy.free"
  android:versionCode="8"
  android:versionName="8"
  installLocation="preferExternal">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".BugsyFreeGame"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your manifest has gone missing

Comment: When uploading to Android market, did you set any country restrictions, or is the error specific about the "incompatibility?". I would perhaps guess there is no external storage in Galaxy Mini but do not know detail.

Comment: Thanks, It has external storage and no country specific stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any tools to help diagnose device and app compatibility.

Try [MOTODEV's App Validator](http://developer.motorola.com/testing/app-validator/). They won't tell you that you will have problems with the Samsung Galaxy Mini, but if your problems with the Mini would also cause problems with some Motorola device, the errors it tells you may help clear that up.

> What is the problem with my manifest?

The Samsung Galaxy Mini may be considered a small-screen device. Try adding a `<supports-screens>` element declaring specifically what screen sizes you support, including small screens.

Also, please seriously reconsider your `<uses-sdk>` element, particularly your chosen `android:targetSdkVersion`. Your app will look out of date on Android 3.0+ devices, and there are already more of those than there are Android 1.5 (a.k.a., API Level 3) devices. If you set `android:targetSdkVersion` to `11` or higher, your app will still run on older devices, but you will adopt the Honeycomb look-and-feel (holographic theme for widgets, action bar, etc.), which will make your app look like it belongs on the newer devices.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding targetSdkVersion I didn't know that. I'm working from the advice here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994039/428280 and as my game self draws at full screen I should be ok.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the mention. We put out a new release of the App Validator as a stand-alone tool last week as well as Eclipse plugins. The web tool is convenient for quick use, but it doesn't get updated as quickly as the Eclipse tools.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came around a strong problem with: **Samsung Galaxy Mini** and **Samsung Galaxy Ace**

I followed all the posts that are in this thread, all very interesting. It solved some problems, but yet no luck with these 2 devices.

In the end, I ended up disactivating a simple feature:

```
<use-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I actually didn't "really" need that feature. 
Paf, my app appeared for these 2 devices right after the new update. :)

So... My piece of advice is: **Use use-feature autofocus ONLY if your app depends on it**

Comment: That's an odd one as those devices do actually have camera's