# My android app is not available through market

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Device Compatibility Issue with Samsung Galaxy Mini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776643/device-compatibility-issue-with-samsung-galaxy-mini)

I created one android app and published it on android market. But, when I try to look for it in the market then it does not appear for Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5770) but it does appear for HTC desire S. But, when I try to run it from eclipse to Samsung phone then it works.

I looked into the developer console and it said that the app is restricted for Samsung galaxy mini because of its manifest file's permissions. Could any one please help me in telling which particular feature is problem for samsung galaxy phone.

My manifest has following permissions -

```
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.screen.landscape
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<use-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

That's the guilty line that makes your app not compatible withe the Galaxy Mini

Remove it and put the update in Google Play.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using zxing library for QR code reading and that camera.autofocus feature is coming from that library. I will see if I can remove it from the library and then update it on the market.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get rid of this autofocus because of the way the library is written. But I will accept your answer anyways cause your solutions was correct.

Comment: Thanks. What about adding android:required="false" ? as suggested by other user? Take care, the library might not work as expected and you might hurt these users!

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you put

```
android:required="false"
```

Would that work? [Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)