# Android: ADs on old Android SDK versions (< 11)

Tags: android, sdk, ads

Browsing the internet I found a lot of ADs SDK for android but all of them (among those I found) need Android SDK 11 or greater and this is a big trouble for me since I developed my apps keeping in mind to give the maximum reasonable compatibility (SDK 3 compatible, optimized for 11 or 15).
Still not enough depressed I ran into the "terms and conditions" of AdSense for mobile and I read something like "every AD found to be related to or referenced from an mobile app will be disabled", so also the idea to add a WebView to the Activity layout referencing a web page vanished...

My question is: how to add ADs keeping compatibility with older devices?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Google's endorsed [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download)? If you look at their [sample download](http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/Android_XML.zip), it uses a minimum SDK of 3. (The target is set to 15, but this is to be expected if you are compiling against 15 as well.)

Comment: There is no compatibility issue by targeting higher SDKs. My apps all target API 16, and I can run them all on Android 2.2 and 2.3. The minimum SDK is what causes restrictions. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994039/1438733).