# android different build versions

Tags: android, versions, android-build, android-version, android-support-library

I have a android app that I'm building in android 2.1. But the time has come to switch to a bigger build. What is the best way to support 2 or more android build versions.
I had some suggestions like:

1. Using git branches for the 2 builds
2. Making the native, first 2.1 app a library project and creating two separate project that will use the library's common classes but
   rewrite all of the controllers
3. Use the library project, two separate project for the different build and whan I have to use a class from the specific build I will
   have to  call something like this from the library project:

   ```
   Class<ExpandableListAdapter> adapterClass = Config.getHotelDistrictAdapterClass();
           hotelAdapter = adapterClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(HotelDistrictListActivity.this,
   ```

   0, hotelList.size(), hotelList,
                       cretedFromAssets);

   where the Config class will counsult a config file that is contained
   in the build versions  and contains the class name for the specific
   build.

   So the scenario will go somothin like this: the lib project will
   call on the Config class then the config class will call on a config
   file in the current build(4.2 or 2.1), the config file will return
   the class name and the Config class will return the class to the lib
   Project and the Lib Project will instanciate the class with the code
   :

   hotelAdapter =
   adapterClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(HotelDistrictListActivity.this,
   0, hotelList.size(), hotelList,cretedFromAssets);

Please suggest what is the better or best way to maintain two separate builds for two android versions, or suggest the way that you use to maintain two ore more android builds.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at AndroidManifest.xml minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion fields. They allow you to support a range of android versions in the same app.

[Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I think I understand the concept of min sdk and target sdk. But do you suggest to use just one project and build it with different targetsdk's? If so there is still the question of how to support and manage different classes, components, xml's and different solutions of the same problem for bought 2.1 and 4.x

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily set your MinSDKVersion to 8 or 7 for and set your Building Target to 16 or 17
this can be done from your Manifest.xml file

Comment: But do I use just one project or two projects, and what happens if I want the design to be different in 2.1 and in 4.0? For example  I want to start to use the action bar in 4.x. How do I maintain the code that i different for the two builds?

Comment: you can use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT , and use a if conditinon to decide what to do if the android id 4 or 2.1