# released the software to Google Market, but release supports zero device

Tags: android

I released the software to Google Market, but release supports zero device.I configured the manifest file: android: targetSdkVersion = "15" />
I use Android version 4.1 compiler. Tried many ways or zero device. I hope someone can help solve the problem. Really thank you!

Comment: Have you activated your apk file?

Comment: I have packaged the signature app. can you help me ?

Comment: You also need to active the app in the Google Play console

Answer (score 0):

You need minSdkVersion:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" 
         android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Comment: Hi , the manifest file I have declared this :<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> ,but don't have userful,It's really Really weird.Can you continue help me ?

Comment: why you write android:targetSdkVersion="17" ,what is the difference when I write targetSdkVersion="15", I try write android:targetSdkVersion="15" ,someone's android device can download it and install it .why why? I almost collapsed .

Comment: see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version

Comment: However, as vmironov pointed out above your APK in Google Play should indicate that it is "in Prod".