# Android Reflection: is it necessary to raise the targetSdk?

Tags: android, reflection

If I use reflection to use a method from a higher Sdk when i can, do I need to raise my targetSdk to that higher sdk or can I keep it at my current, lower version?

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994039/1685098, http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html.

Although those resources suggest you should raise your targetSdk, none of them specifically state that you *must*.

Note especially the android developer documentation, however, which recommends you set targetSdk to the highest SDK level you have checked against.

Comment: I had seen the blogpost, i guess i was hoping to hear from someone explicitly if I could get away with not raising the targetSdk.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, which is why I mentioned the guidelines recommending that you raise targetSdk anyway. Is there any reason why you don't want to raise it?

Comment: it can cause problems if i dont know the side effects or handle them properly. e.g. in sdk 11 if i want to handle screen orientation changes i have to handle screen_size changes as well or else my activity gets destroyed and recreated. i'm buckling down and reading thru the docs tho i think you do actually have to raise it from my impression