# Can't register more than one Sensor in Android Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

I have a service which is called from an Activity. This Service Registers all Sensors and Registers Listener against them.

**EDIT: I have removed the two lines in onSensorChange()**

```
**sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        sensorManager = null;**
```

**AND now it works. WHY?**

The Problem is that when I do them one at a time, my application works fine but if I register more than one sensor, My application crashes.

Here is the OnCreate Function of my Service:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        //mAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mMagnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        //mGyro = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        //      mLinearAccelertion = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);

        //sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        //sensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyro, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        //sensorManager.registerListener(this, mLinearAccelertion, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    }
```

Here is my onSensorChanged Function:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Heelooo" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        float[] values = event.values;
        Sensor mSensor = event.sensor;
        boolean res = CalculatePosition.calculateNewPosition(4.5F,5.3F);
        if(res){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //CalculatePosition.test(event);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        sensorManager = null;
}
```

I am starting the service like this in MyActivity onCreate Function:

```
intent = new Intent(this, CustomSensorService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

[image: The Log Cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OnSensorChanged event is setting the sensorManager to Null so as soon as a sensor is fired no more can be set.

**EDIT**

If you want each sensor to use a different listener, use something like this instead of implementing the methods on your activity:

```
private void SetupSensors() {
    sensorManager.registerListener(MagneticListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

private SensorEventListener MagneticListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        // Code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
};
```

Comment: How do I stop the SensorListener then?

Comment: You stop it the way you are doing already but you cannot then register another listener after you have set the sensorManager to null. Either don't nullify the sensorManager or assign another instance of the manager.

Comment: sensorManager.unregisterListener(this); This line will Unregister All Sensors Listeners?

Comment: Basically as soon as you set the listener, it fires, runs the listener code which nullifies it. The code then returns and tries to set another listener but sensorManager is now null so it throws an NPE

Comment: Yes. You are using the same listener in all sensors.