# MinSdk and TargetSdk

Tags: android

Enlighten me in a simple way. Based on my understanding, if you have a minsdk set to 14 and target sdk to 19 means that your app can use the new features of the api 19 and is backward compatible up to 14.

So your app is compatible in versions 14 to 19 and not compatible below 14. Is that right?

Comment: I believe that is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is almost correct. Your app would work with any device above version 14, but not below, and is designed for version 19 (usually means compiled and tested using that API level). But, unless you specify android:maxSdkVersion it will continue to work with newer versions than the target.

T[his page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) on the android dev site goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You are partly right:

by specifying minSDKVersion you tell android to prevent user from install on lower versions.
by specifying targerSDKVersion you tell the platform that you have tested your app on this version. It enables platform to disable the features are not necessary for target or enable the ones which are.
And as mentioned here:

[Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

"It simply informs the platform that you have tested against the target version and the platform should not perform any extra work to maintain forward-compatibility with the target version."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not work below API 14, is compatible in all versions above 14 and can use features all the way up to 19. Any devices running higher than 19 will run the app in compatibility mode for 19 if necessary