# Should I install all SDKs to Upload Unity Game to Google Play?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

My question is **Should I install all SDK versions or only latest version** (...API24,API25,API26,API27,API28,API29,API30,API31,API32...) **is enough for uploading my unity game to google play?** I have just installed the latest API version(Currently API32).
But in Google Play there could be players which has lower version of API like API24.
My question is also for JDKs and NKDs If it these have the same solutions. Does it important(For Google Play) to have latest version of STK JDK NDK?
Edit:I adjust as use maximum API level in unity

Note:I imagine like if I made mistake about this ,some of players can not play my game. If It is real, I don't want to lose some players. I imagine like this so please help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to set the target SDK to API30, so that most of players can run your game perfectly.

These articles might help:

Meet Google Play's target API level requirement:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Stackoverflow user question:
[Will my application be visible to devices higher than my targetSdkVersion in Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245483/will-my-application-be-visible-to-devices-higher-than-my-targetsdkversion-in-goo)

Comment: Google Play needs a minimum TargetAPI of 30 from August 2021 (or November 2021 for app updates)

Comment: Oh you are right sorry, I will fix that. By the way did it help your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, It takes time to read and understand all it. I am still searching but this is the best I have on internet. Thank you again. And thanks for  your critical answer chrisbtoo.

Comment: [Will my application be visible to devices higher than my targetSdkVersion in Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245483/will-my-application-be-visible-to-devices-higher-than-my-targetsdkversion-in-goo) here it says: devices has higher API level can see lover API apps/games. What about visa versa? So shall we  use 30API level as @chrisbtoo said, or shall we use laters API version(currently API32)? What if lower API level devices can not see our apps/games?

Comment: @SeyAhYo you can target an API version higher than the the required on, but I'd say you're better off with 31 rather than 32 at the moment, as 32 hasn't been finalized yet. Your `minSdkVersion` specifies the minimum API required, and it should run on anything above that. FWIW my apps generally have a `minSdkVersion` of 21 (Android 5).