# How to set android target level 21

Tags: android, gradle

I recently finished developing my app. and I want to change the target API level of the app to 21. Should I change it to 21 or leave it at 19?
Also what changes would I have to make to the gradle file to make the target set to 21?
Thanks

Comment: [Set it to 21](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994039/4428462). To change it in gradle files, you only need to replace 19 with 21 where appropriate. (usually in build.gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the module's `build.gradle` file (NOT the one for the project) and replace 19 with 21. It should look similar to below

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Also change this in the manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21"></uses-sdk>
```

Comment: what version should I set for compile'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0', should I change them to 21 instead of 19

Comment: You could change it to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'` . Also you could accept the answer instead of upvoting ..