# Some constants get cut out from the apk which causes an error in runtime

Tags: java, android

An Android I have compiles well but at runtime it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: android.os.Build$VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Build$VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

For this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
  //....
}


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  //.....
```

The similar error gets thrown for `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH`.

These constants do exist when I click on them in IDE but I believe they somehow get cut out from the result apk.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version

Comment: @PM77-1, thanks but how's it applicable to my case?