# Cannot find symbol ClientCertRequest on CordovaLib compilation from cordova-android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, android-sdk-tools

I am currently building a PhoneGap app, with the following tools versions:

- `npm@2.5.1`
- `cordova@3.6.0-0.2.9`
- `cordova-android@3.6.0`

In order to install a plugin which requires `cordova-android` v4+, I tried to install:

- `cordova@5.1.1`
- `cordova-android@4.0.2`

However, the `cordova build` command doesn't work anymore. Here are the first lines referencing to compilation errors:

```
Running: /Users/Pierre/Documents/project/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/Pierre/Documents/project/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
/Users/Pierre/Documents/project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: package android.webkit
/Users/Pierre/Documents/project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    private final ClientCertRequest request;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
```

From what I understand, [the ClientCertRequest symbol has been introduced by the Android API level 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ClientCertRequest.html), and my `cordova build` is trying to compile using an older level.

I tried to force the use of the API level 21.

The file `/Users/Pierre/Documents/project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties` contains the following:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-19
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

So I tried to create a sibling file `ant.properties` containing:

```
target=android-21
```

but it doesn't change anything.

I also tried a bunch of other modifications which would be too long to describe here, but everything ends up to be overwritten.

Here is a screenshot of the Android tools installed on my system:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like it is still building with `target=android-19`. Did you changed the AndroidManifest.xml to the required `21` version?

[Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Yep I tried that. I modified both `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` and `platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml` and it doesn't have any effect.