# What versions of Android can an app developed with Android Studio be used on?

Tags: android-studio

I was getting ready to download and install Android Studio.  But as best I could tell, it Android Studio will create an app for use on Andriod 6 (Marshmallow).  What about previous versions of android?

On the features list at the Android Studio page, it says "Android 6.0 Marshmallow".  I'm hoping that just means that it INCLUDES support for Marshmallow but I wasn't sure.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can target whatever minimum SDK version you want using Android Studio. To learn how, check this question/answer: [Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

It discusses Eclipse, but is still relevant to AS.

Comment: ok thanks.  I really didn't want to download and install AS and THEN find out that it can't target older versions of Android.