# How to build apps with minimum Android version required in Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, platform-specific

I am learning Cordova by going through the docs and many blogs. I am able to create the basic skeleton of the Cordova app using `cordova create`, and can add the platform using `cordova platform add android`.

But I want to know how can I add the platform so that the apps I build will require API level 22 and above (i.e. API level not below 22)?

Comment: what does it mean API level 22 and above but not below 22?

Comment: @DS Dharma I mean that I want to make an app that is supported from android lollipop version and above but not below that.

Comment: May I know why my question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

([Cordova Android platform guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/))

Comment: I am running cordova-android 6.X.X and I want to support from api level 22 so I should change 14 to 22. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, so to check if it's working or not I have to set up an emulator with android version less than 22 and check whether it's installing or not? Is that right? And what is the use of targetsdkversion?

Comment: Normally yes. 
Add `targetSdkVersion` with value to 22 too. Read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version#answer-4568358) for a good explaination

Comment: Ok, I gotta try this out. Can you kindly take a look at another [cordova question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44648751/3697102)